# Rendering an animation the way 3D view looks

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

Is there some way to render *exactly* whats in the camera view in the 3D view? By that I mean just like a screenshot really, all paths, lamps, and cameras, just like things look in the camera view. The reason I can't just take a screenshot is that I need an animation and it would be too cumbersome to take 1000+ screenshots!

Comment: You mean render exactly what you see in `Camera View` in `Object Mode` and `Solid` viewport shading? If so, then you could do an `OpenGL` render by going to `Render > OpenGL Image`

Comment: I knew it would be something simple! I just didn't know what it was :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can [render using *OpenGL*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Vitals/Quick_render), by going to *Info > Header > Render > OpenGL Render Image*:

[image]

Or by clicking on the icons in *3D view > Header*:

[image]

Comment: I have been looking for this my whole life. Awesome !