# Can I record unrendered scene/animation?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I like how 3D View exposes me the auxiliary objects, like cameras, selected object coordinate system and TrackTo line. But all auxiliary objects are removed in the rendered view, that is stored to output device by animation. Can I render the animation in Solid view instead of Render, for instance?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18251/rendering-an-animation-the-way-3d-view-looks. You could switch between objects to render with *Only Render* option in the *Properties* panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try selecting Render > Render OpenGL Animation.  That should give you the results you want.

Comment: I wonder why do you call unrendered view "OpenGL". Is it because rendered is private/closed somehow?

Comment: @LittleAlien Um, no.  [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org) stands for Open Graphics Language, it is an incredibly common rendering framework.  Blender uses it to display the viewport in real-time, but when doing renders, there are render engines that give more realistic (or not so realistic) looks.  Blender has two engines built in, Blender Internal (the default and looks similar to the viewport, but has not been worked on for a while), and Cycles (realistic looking renders, but they take longer).